# What should be the notation for CDF?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, notation

I have conditional PDF:

$$f_{Z \mid Z > t}(z) = \frac{f_Z(z)}{P(Z > t)}$$

Now I want to compute the CDF. What should be the notation of CDF? 
$F_{Z \mid Z > t}(z)$ or $P(Z \leq z \mid Z > t)$?

${{}}$

Comment: When conditioning on events $A$, I prefer $\mathbb{P}(Z\leq z| A)$, when conditioning on the specific events $Y=y$ (say) then I write $F(z|y):=\mathbb{P}(Z\leq z| Y=y)$.

Comment: So, you would write $P(Z \leq z \mid Z > t)$?

Comment: Yup. I like this notation because of how it works with the LTP: $F(z)=\int F(z|y)f_Y(y)dy$ vs $\mathbb{P}(Z\leq z)=\mathbb{P}(Z\leq z|A)\mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{P}(Z\leq z |A^c)\mathbb{P}(A^c)$